# Combine Socrata Latitude and Longitude columns to form Point-type Location column

Tags: socrata, soda

I'm trying to figure out how to use the [`within_circle(...)`](http://dev.socrata.com/docs/functions/within_circle.html) function with the Socrata-based [Food Establishment Inspection data set](https://data.kingcounty.gov/dataset/Food-Establishment-Inspection-Data/f29f-zza5). Unfortunately it appears the data set does not have the required Point datatype column but rather two Number columns with Latitude and Longitude. How can I create a virtual/calculated Point-type Location column based on Latitude and Longitude so I can use `within_circle(...)`?

Comment: Additionally if anyone knows I'm curious if `within_circle` can sort by distance from the given point?

Comment: The Location datatype column (http://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/location.html) does exist in this dataset but it appears to be blank for all records. In order to take advantage of within_circle the dataset owner must update the Location column. I am in contact with the data owners and have given them guidance to make this change when publishing the data. I will post an update if they make the change to the dataset.